# Somando Valores de um Array Agrupando pela Chave

Tags: php, html, array, mysqli, post

Eu postei aqui uma dúvida essa semana, mas ela foi negativada por falta de mais informação, de lá para cá acabei solucionando o problema em questão, com isso vou deixar aqui a solução que encontrei e caso queiram implementar fiquem a vontade.

(1) Qual era o problema? Eu tinha um formulário(vide abaixo) de perguntas, onde o usuário insere números, eu preciso somar estes números de acordo com os nomes dos campos, agrupando eles, tenho então 2 af_bm1, 2 af_a e 2 af_om1.

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-date">
    <input class="af af_1" type="text" name="af_bm1_2"> <span>Pergunta 1</span>
    <input class="af af_2" type="text" name="af_om1_1"> <span>Pergunta 2</span>
    <input class="af af_3" type="text" name="af_a_1"> <span>Pergunta 3</span>
    <input class="af af_4" type="text" name="af_a_2"> <span>Pergunta 4</span>
    <input class="af af_5" type="text" name="af_om1_2"> <span>Pergunta 5</span>
    <input class="af af_6" type="text" name="af_bm1_1"> <span>Pergunta 6</span>
</form>
```

Como não consegui chegar a um código com o formulário neste formato, eu mudei os nomes dos campos para gerar um array diferente e já fazer o agrupamento dos campos com nome semelhantes, os campos então ficaram assim:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-date">
    <input class="af af_1" type="text" name="af_bm1[1]"> <span>Pergunta 1</span>
    <input class="af af_2" type="text" name="af_om1[1]"> <span>Pergunta 2</span>
    <input class="af af_3" type="text" name="af_a[1]"> <span>Pergunta 3</span>
    <input class="af af_4" type="text" name="af_a[2]"> <span>Pergunta 4</span>
    <input class="af af_5" type="text" name="af_om1[2]"> <span>Pergunta 5</span>
    <input class="af af_6" type="text" name="af_bm1[1]"> <span>Pergunta 6</span>
</form>
```

Dessa forma pude usar um `foreach()` em conjunto com um `array_sum()`, ficando assim:

```
$vars = $_POST; //Não faça isso em casa!!!
                
$res_totais = array();

foreach ($vars as $key => $value){
    $res_totais[$key] = array_sum($value);
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($res_totais); echo '</pre>';
```

Resutado:

```
Array(
    [af_a] => 15
    [af_bm1] => 24
    [af_om1] => 30
)
```

Consegui o resultado esperado, mas minha dúvida continuou, e se eu não pudesse mudar os nomes dos campos, como eu conseguiria este resultado?

Comment: uma pergunta, ele sempre ira seguir esse padrao de numero ?

Comment: Sim, os semelhantes terão numeração sequencial af_a_1, af_a_2, af_a_3, na tela eles ficaram embaralhados, para evitar reconhecimento do padrão que estão dispostos.

Comment: verifica se minha resposta lhe ajuda

Comment: adicionei um outro exemplo com um filtro de quais chave vc quer que seja contado assim vc pode fazer filtros e so contar as que lhe interesa no momento

Comment: eai minha respostas ajudou?

Comment: Vou testar elas daqui a pouco, mas pelo que parece irão ajudar sim.

Comment: Blz , caso de certo marque como correta , caso algo de errado me avisa que eu posso tentar ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uma das soluções que encontrei ja que segue sempre esse padrão seria essa

```
    function agrupamento($array_post)
    {
        $array_new = [];
        foreach ($array_post as $k => $v) {
            //retirar o numero e o caracter final do post
            $novachave = substr($k, 0, -2);
            //verifico se ela ja foi setada caso foi verifica se e um numero
            if (isset($array_new[$novachave]) and is_numeric($v)) {
                $array_new[$novachave] =  $array_new[$novachave] + $v;
                
                //verifica se e um numero 
            }elseif(is_numeric($v)){
                $array_new[$novachave]=$v;
            }
        }
        return $array_new;
    }
agrupamento($_POST);
```

Resposta:

```
[ 
   [af_bm1] => 3,
   [af_om1] => 7 ,
   [af_a] => 11
]
```

exemplo 2

```
function agrupamentocomfiltro($array_post)
{
    $array_new = [];
    $chavepermitidas = ['af_a', 'af_bm1', 'af_om1'];
    foreach ($array_post as $k => $v) {
        //controlador da chave
        $controlador = 0;

        //retirar o numero final do post
        $novachave = substr($k, 0, -2);

        //varre todas as chaves que você permitiu se contada
        foreach ($chavepermitidas as $value_permitido) {
            //verifica se a chave atual do POST esta na lista de chaves permitida
            if ($novachave == $value_permitido) {
                //caso esteja seta o controlador para 1 e sai do loop
                $controlador = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        // verifica se o controlador e 1
        if ($controlador == 1) {

            //verifico se ela ja foi setada caso foi verifica se e um numero
            if (isset($array_new[$novachave]) and is_numeric($v)) {
                $array_new[$novachave] = $array_new[$novachave] + $v;

                //verifica se e um numero
            } elseif (is_numeric($v)) {
                $array_new[$novachave] = $v;
            }
        }
    }
    return $array_new;
}
```

Comment: Deram super certo, todas as duas versões, só tive que alterar as `[]` e `['af_a', 'af_bm1', 'af_om1']` para `array()` e `array('af_a', 'af_bm1', 'af_om1'])`. Acredito que devido a versão do PHP do server que trabalho.